# Getting incorrect result with XQuery?

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Below is the XMl File -

```
<Chapters>
  <Chapter n="1">
    <Desc>....</Desc>
    <References>
       <BookRef>HTML : in 21 Days</BookRef>
       <Page>12, 13</Page>
       <BookRef>HTML : Unlimited</BookRef>
       <Page>21, 22</Page>
       <BookRef>The Complete Reference - HTML</BookRef>
       <Page>32-35</Page>
    </References>
  </Chapter>
  <Chapter n="2">
    <Desc>....</Desc>
    <References>
       <BookRef>HTML : in 21 Days</BookRef>
       <Page>52, 53</Page>
       <BookRef>The Complete Reference - HTML</BookRef>
       <Page>132-145</Page>
       <BookRef>The Complete Reference - Javascript</BookRef>
       <Page>132-145</Page>
    </References>
  </Chapter>
</Chapters>
```

I am trying to list 
- all the  containing `HTML` word using
`/Chapters/Chapter/References[BookRef contains text 'HTML']/BookRef`

But all  are being displayed...!! What will be the XQuery to retrieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You want**:

```
/Chapters/Chapter/References/BookRef[contains(., 'HTML')]
```

Comment: Dimitre-> One more question.. suppose the <BookRef> tag contains a book named "The Complete Reference - DHTML" as a text part, the above query will return this too as a result. How to get the exact result then?

Comment: @Pratik: You can select only those `Bookref` elements whose string contents starts with "HTML". Instead of `contains()` use: `starts-with(., 'HTML')`

Comment: @Pratik: or perhaps you might want to match on entire words. Replace the `contains` with: `tokenize(., '\s+') = 'HTML'`

Answer (score 3):

Try the following one:

```
/Chapters/Chapter/References/BookRef[. contains text 'HTML']
```

Otherwise, all `References` nodes will be returned that have a `BookRef` node containing `HTML`, and the following step will return all `BookRef` nodes (i.e., you lose the information which of the BookRef nodes had the searched token).

Comment: This solution works fine, you can try it live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#IKUBaOuQ65myUJLdTtXTA7c7Jos=

Answer (score 2):

Use XPath = `/Chapters/Chapter/References/BookRef[contains(., 'HTML')]`